# exit temporary modified file without saving and jump back to my previous viewing place in vim

Tags: vim

In `vim`, I am viewing a file, and then opened a temporary file and did some modification, then I want to get back to the original file. I typed `ctrl-o`, but then I got `E37: No write since last change (add ! to override)`

How can I exit temporary modified file without saving and jump back to my previous viewing place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By turning on `'hidden'` you can jump between unsaved buffers without the `E37` error messages. Don't worry vim will stop you from exiting without saving your changes unless you use something like `:q!`.

```
set hidden
```

See `:h 'hidden'` for more information.

Answer (score 1):

From [vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_buffer_FAQ),

> You can set the following options to create a scratch (temporary)
>   buffer:
>
> ```
> :set buftype=nofile
> :set bufhidden=hide
> :setlocal noswapfile
> ```

With these settings, you can switch out of the temp buffer without requiring a write.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a solution specifically for temporary files then A.E Drew's answer is correct.

If you're looking for a general solution to "How do I switch to a different buffer without saving changes in the current buffer?" Then just `set hidden` in your .vimrc.